# Did herders/horde people get constipation from not eating any vegetables or fiber?

Tags: health

Seeing as modern day humans get constipation regularly on a carnivore diet, and the horde certainly werent able to trade for fiber-rich foods on a daily basis it is sensible to say that they should be prone to get constipation. Is this a fact or is there any evidence?

Comment: *"the horde certainly werent able to trade for fibers on a daily basis"* Would they need to? For example, grains can be stored for a long a time. Also, please let us know where you have looked already so that others don't duplicate your research. Thank you.

Comment: A first google search says that "The Horde" lived on animal products and gathered fruit and vegetables. That means milk, cheese, yoghurt, fruit and vegetables. My first google search hit might be wrong though. While they probably ate more meat then a poor farmer on special occasions, what is your source for assuming they ate lots of meat regularly?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786). Question relies on undocumented assumptions. The horde might acquire high fiber foods through conquest/exploitation as well as trade.  Unclear what the impact of high exercise lifestyle might have on constipation.

Comment: e.g. [WorldHistory](https://www.worldhistory.org/article/1451/food--drink-in-the-mongol-empire/)) which says "Nomads are also gatherers, and the Mongols collected useful dietary supplements such as wild vegetables, roots, tubers, mushrooms, grains, berries, and other fruit they came across in nature or via trade. "

Comment: [Potential sources](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/3vrlqx/what_kind_of_food_would_mongol_warriors_have/) [Columbia](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/3vrlqx/what_kind_of_food_would_mongol_warriors_have/) "Ögödei
Qa’an, Chinggis’. . .  issued [an edict (yasa)] to the effect that every day five hundred
wagons fully loaded with food and drink should arrive [in Qara-Qorum (Khara Khorum) in central Outer Mongolia] from the [Mongols’ Chinese] provinces  . . . . For [grain] and [wine] there were provided great wagons drawn by six oxen each."

Comment: Also relevant [millet](https://www.financialexpress.com/lifestyle/science/millet-bridged-gap-between-hunter-gathering-and-farming/178693/) which can be gathered, and several sources suggest it was part  of the Mongol diet.

Comment: Might want to clarify whether you want "herders" or the "Horde". Most of us  have answered based on the assumption that you mean horde.  Herders can augment with gathering much more easily.

Answer (score 1):

If we take Mongolia as an example, the traditional diet during the summer months consists mostly of milk products. Not sure if that counts as carnivore. Meat is mostly consumed during winter. The more northern parts of the country have a variety of berries and also some vegetables such as Altai onions (Allium altaicum).

But more importantly, most cereals and vegetables that can be grown in Central/Northern Europe *can* also be grown in Mongolia. The vegetation period is similar and the main limiting factor is availability of water. Nowadays Mongolians produce considerable amounts of cereals and vegetables on their own.

Of course that does not yet mean Mongolians grew cereals in the past. However, at least [one study](https://www.shh.mpg.de/1644915/mongolian-millets) suggests that from the times of the Xiongnu to the times of the Mongol Empire, millet was an important part of the diet in what is now Mongolia.

Comment: Milk doesn't provide fiber and doesn't answer the question.